# How to plot an implicit function; how to plot contours of a surface

Tags: plotting, implicit

How can I plot the circle $(x-4)^2 +(y-4)^2 = 4$ and two level curves of $f(x,y)=x^3 + y^3 - 3xy$ on *Mathematica*. I have tried using the `ContourPlot` command. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Are these two curves meant to be plotted together?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested earlier for the circle, you should use `==` instead of `=`. Note the major difference in the meaning between these 2 symbols. `=` means assignment, i.e., you are *defining* or *setting* the LHS to be the RHS. On the other hand `==` is a logical operator that makes the expression evaluates to `True` if, and only if the LHS value is the same as the RHS value.

```
ContourPlot[ (x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2 == 4, {x, 1, 7}, {y, 1, 7}]
```

[image]

As for the second, just use `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[ x^3 + y^3 - 3 x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
 Show[ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 - 3 x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
      Contours -> {1, 100}, ContourShading -> False],
     ContourPlot[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
      Contours -> {4}, ContourShading -> False]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Here's way of creating the plot by using regions.

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2 == 4, {x, y}];
r2[k_] := ImplicitRegion[x^3 + y^3 - 3 x y == k, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[RegionUnion[r1, r2[1], r2[100]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Stephen, copying and pasting your source code does not reproduce the figure. Can you revisit your answer ?

Comment: I see you have now fixed the typo. I should really check that my code works AFTER I have finished doing all of my editing ...

Comment: Yes, should have waited more, but I saw you weren't online and decided to do it myself :D ..